# Select a random element from an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to select a random element from my array.

However, sometimes I am getting an index out of bounds error, even though I accounted for the array starting at 0 by adding 1 to the maximum value of the index.

```
from random import randint

names = ['Sam', 'Paul', 'Mark', 'Simon', 'Sean', 'Samantha', 'Ellen']
random_name = names[randint(0, len(array)+1)]

print(random_name)
```

I only get an index out of bounds error sometimes?

Comment: How many elements are in your array? What is the maximum legal index?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i understand now thaks to the below amswer there are 7 elements and the max legal index is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ***adding*** `1` you need to ***subtract*** `1` from the length of the `names`, since in python the initial element of a list is assigned the index `0`:

`random_name = names[randint(0, len(names)-1)]`

---

**Alternative solution**

However, for this particular case, I think using **[random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice)** would be more appropriate, especially since you don't have to worry about list indexes at all when you use it:

```
>>> import random
>>> names = ['Sam', 'Paul', 'Mark', 'Simon', 'Sean', 'Samantha', 'Ellen']
>>> random.choice(names)
'Mark'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation I had it mixed up was stuck on this for the past hour. 

Comment: @HwoaRang no problem you nearly had it!

Answer (score 3):

why not just use choice?

```
import random

names = ['Sam', 'Paul', 'Mark', 'Simon', 'Sean', 'Samantha', 'Ellen']
random_name = random.choice(names)

print(random_name)
```